# Is it possible to add css dynamically from admin panel using CodeIgniter

Tags: php, css, codeigniter

I have been trying to do this for quite a long time. I don't know whether it is possible or not. Searched the internet a lot but no demos or samples were available.

Is it possible to add css dynamically from the admin panel using codeigniter. I have seen this feature in wordpress. I am trying to a shorter version of that.
So when the admin changes the values using a form, that values should be stored into db & from there it is fetched & shown in style.css page. Possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes you can do that but the css which will be fetched from db can be set by inner style sheet or in header etc, like
you have fetched propertise from db and now you are into view so your code will be like this
Controller:

```
function index(){
    $data['css_style'] = $this->css_model->get_styles();
    $this->load->view("myview",$data);
}
```

View:

```
<?php
    $toShow = "<style>";
    foreach($css_style as $one_property)
    {
        $toShow .= $one_property['name'].":".$one_property['value'].";";
    }
    $toShow .= "</style>";
    echo $toShow;
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

This tutorials will help you, how to add php variables (*In your case database values*)  to  css file

http://css-tricks.com/css-variables-with-php/